# Can different Aces have different values?

Tags: scoring, blackjack

I understand that **Aces** are worth either **1 Point** or **11 Points**, depending on the player's will. But how are multiple Aces valued? Here are some examples:

> **Ace, Nine, Ace**
>
> Is this always x+9+x, where:
>
> **Case 1:**
>
> x = 1 or x = 11;
>
> *(This hand would always be 11 or 31)*
>
> **Or can this be x+10+y, where:**
>
> **Case 2:**
>
> x = 1 or x = 11;
>
> y = 1 or y = 11
>
> *(This hand can be 11, 21, 21 or 31)*

Comment: An ace is either 1 or 11, not 1 or 10.

Comment: Ooops, @TimLymington is right, I got distracted and counted Aces as 10 not 11. However the math checks out (for what I meant to reproduce) if I don't use a King, but use an Ace. I edited to reflect that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hand is always scored to give the best possible value for the player, such that they have the highest score they can get without going bust. **The player never chooses the values or the score**; it is decided by the rule and the cards on the table.
A+A+X will always be valued as 12+X, unless this would bust, in which case it must be valued as 12 (since the only such X is a ten-value card, and therefore the only non-bust score is for both aces to be one-value).
*Source: professional experience dealing in a regulated casino.*

Comment: Alrighty, that's the idea I had but just to be sure =)

Good explanation of the ruling btw

Answer (score 5):

First off Ace value is either 1 or 11 (this is why face+ace is a blackjack)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack

Second you choose what it is worth, but most places will assume you want 11 unless it will bust you

So in your hand you can choose between 12,22,22,32

Answer (score 0):

Each ace has it's value determined separately. If you somehow drew 4 aces, you could have 4, 14, 24, 34, or 44 as the value of your hand.