# Can multiple Blackjack Aces have value 1?

Tags: blackjack

What will be the value of this hand?

```
2, 9, A, 4, A
```

May it be **17**?
Or it must be 27?

In this situation can every Ace count as 1, or there must be one Ace as 11?

Comment: The question already has an answer here: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/31423/can-different-aces-have-different-values

Comment: I saw it, his question was slightly different, but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each Ace may be counted as one or as eleven.

[Bicycle](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/blackjack/)

> It is up to each individual player if an ace is worth 1 or 11. Face cards are 10 and any other card is its pip value.

[Poker Casino](https://www.pokerstarscasino.com/games/blackjack/rules/?no_redirect=1)

> Aces can have two different values, of either one or eleven (you can choose which).